# Path to tcl/tk and python3 linux

Tags: tkinter, tcl, python-3.5

Having a really hard time setting this path after downloading tcl/tk. Went in to the command line to try and append tcl/tk to sys.path and then I want to ultimately run tk in pycharm.  What exactly should I append to my python3 path? The directory that has activeTcl? A certain file in that directory?

```
sys.path
['', '/usr/local/lib/python35.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python3.5', '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/plat-linux', '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages', '/root/Downloads/ActiveTcl8.5.18.0.298892-linux-x86_64-threaded/']
```

That is the path I am currently using. The last (activeTcl) is the one that I appended. Also do I need to do anything to pycharm to get it to call this path? Any ideas?

Comment: Forgot to mention I'm running a version of linux

Comment: Your distro should come with Python and TCL/Tk installed.  If not, use the distro's package manager to install it as it will know where it should be installed.   You can modify the python search path in ~/.bashrc --> export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/other/directory/you/want/:/additional/dir

Comment: Okay Ill give that a shot. Thanks